# SonarQube server can not be reached from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli)
[Error] SonarQube server [https://sonarqube.test.com:9000] can not be reached

Note: Sonarqube Version 6.0, Jenkins Version 2.62, SonarQube Scanner For Jenkins Version 2.61

Comment: what are you trying to reach ? https://sonarqube.test.com:9000 ? what action do you perform ?

Comment: I am trying to setup Sonarqube with Jenkins to analyze projects. However, Sonarqube is unreachable from Jenkins or Sonar-Runner itself. Please let me know if you have any hits. Thanks.

Comment: configure sonarqube instance in the jenkins configuration page. Be sure that you have an sonarqube instance well running before.

Comment: I have configured in Jenkins as well but build has been failed. Not sure why Sonarqube is unreachable from Jenkins and sonar runner. There is no error log in Sonarqube log though.

Comment: first access your sonarqube dashboard in a browser, is it ok ?

Comment: I have no problem accessing Sonarqube dashboard and creating user accounts in Sonarqube at all.

Comment: so use the same adress in jenkins configuration settings, mm ?

Comment: I have used the same configuration in Jenkins. It is not only issue with Jenkins. When I execute Sonar Scanner from command line I get the same error message  with connect timed out.

Comment: please paste full message error

Comment: I can browse my sonarqube webpage (https://mysonarqubepage.com) with no issue but get the error message only when I execute sonar scanner or jenkins build. Also, when I execute sonar scanner and jenkins build using http://localhost:9000 instead of https://mysonarqubepage.com, I don't have any issue. Could it be https issue?

Comment: " I don't have any issue." -> you mean the analyse is well done and sonarqube can be reached ? In this case yes it seems you have a network resolution problem

Comment: I can do analysis with http in localhost but not with https in mysonarqubepage.com although webpage is valid and secured with ssl.

Comment: looks like your SonarServer is running on port 443 with SSL configured. Have you added the certificate as a trusted certificate on the Jenkins server (JRe/Cacert)?